# Deciding positive definite function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Is there a characterization other than using Bochners Theorem (computing its Fourier transform) to decide whether the function is positive definite function or not?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

For example to decide positive definiteness of this function.

$$f(x)=\frac{\cosh(7x)\cosh(6x)\cosh(2x)}{\cosh(8x)\cosh^{2}(4x)}$$

Is $f(x)$ positive definite function or not?

I have an idea to use this theorem.

for $a,b> 0$, $\frac{\cosh(ax)}{\cosh^{2}(bx)}$ is positive definite function if and only if $a\leq b$.
And the fact that the product of two positive  definite function is positive definite function.

But I do not have an idea how to manipulate such function to decide whether $f(x)$ is positive definite function or not.
Because to decide the positive definiteness of $f(x)$ by computing its Fourier transform for such function is very tedious and complicated.

I want a way something like this to decide positive definiteness of $f(x)$. (avoiding Bochner theorem and harnessing the above theorem)

"The function $\frac{\cosh(ax)}{\cosh(bx)\cosh(cx)}$ with $a,b,c>0$ is positive definite functions if and only if $a\leq \max\{b,c\}$ "

Proof. 
Assume that the function is positive definite and $b\geq c$. Then the product $$\frac{\cosh(ax)}{\cosh(bx)\cosh(cx)}\times \frac{\cosh(cx)}{\cosh(bx)}=\frac{\cosh(ax)}{\cosh^{2}(bx)}$$
 is also positive definite which implies by the above theorem that $a\leq b$. The converse is trivial due to the fact that the product of two positive definite function is positive definite function.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: What kind of function ? Very vague question so far.

Comment: $\frac{\cosh(7x)\cosh(6x)\cosh(2x)}{\cosh(8x)\cosh^{2}(4x)}$ for example

Answer (score 1):

In my engineering classes we weren't taught about Bochner's Theorem. We used the following:

You can select a class K function which is the lower bound.
That is:

$\:\:\:\:$find $\alpha (\bullet) \in R_+ \rightarrow R $ that is strictly increasing, continuous, and with a(0) = 0.

then if your function f(t,x) satisfies

f(t,0) = 0 and f(t,x) $\ge \alpha(|x|) \:\: for\:\: x \in R^n, t\ge 0$

it is positive definite.

Note there are more "rules" which can be applied to avoid the Laplace Transform.  See [page 3 of METRIC SPACES AND POSITIVE DEFINITE FUNCTIONS by I. J. Schoenberg](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1938-044-03/S0002-9947-1938-1501980-0/S0002-9947-1938-1501980-0.pdf)